# gradle buid error :No such property: COMPILE_SDK for class: org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, gradle

I added a gradle.properties in the project，the content like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0G2Z.png)

and this is my main gradle
[content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH9X5.png)

but it build error :`No such property: COMPILE_SDK for class: org.gradle.api.Project` .some body help me,thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You better do like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lancoo.liberalstudy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName 1.0
    }
}
```

as `gradle.properties` file will not recognize those variables